# Retrieve list of updated files in post-receive hook using detached work tree

Tags: git, web-deployment

I push updates to repo with a 'detached work tree' from which Apache serves its files. Using the post-receive hook script I need a list of the changed files in order to update their permissions as required by our suphp. However, it does not work. Any ideas why not?

```
GIT_WORK_TREE=/srv/www/live/ files=`git diff ..FETCH_HEAD --name-only --diff-filter=ACMRTUXB`
GIT_WORK_TREE=/srv/www/live/ sudo -u www-run /usr/bin/git checkout -f
for file in $files
do
     if [[ $file == *.php ]]
     then
             chmod 600 $file
     else
             chmod 644 $file
     fi
 done
```

Contents of .git/config

```
[core]
        repositoryformatversion = 0
        filemode = true
        bare = false
        logallrefupdates = true
        sharedrepository = 1
        worktree = /srv/www/live/
[receive]
        denyNonFastforwards = true
        denycurrentbranch = ignore
```

Comment: what doesn't work? do you get an error?

Comment: also why do you say it's bare? I see `bare=false` in config

Comment: No, there are no errors or any output on the client doing the push. I didn't mean bare, I will edit that out.

Comment: why not ensure that all permissions are as they should be, every time, rather than just updating the files which git says are changed?

Comment: have you checked that you loop over the right files?

Comment: for me I see ambiguous argument ..FETCH_HEAD unknown revision